# changing the meta key in emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, key-binding

I am running emacs 24.3 through the terminal on OS X 10.8.4. I would like to modify the meta-key which is currently set to be the ESC key. I have successfully changed the meta-key from ESC to option/alt however I am interested in remapping the meta-key to be the left-shift key.

1. How can I change the meta-key in emacs running from the terminal to any other key?
2. Specifically, I would like to change the meta-key to left-shift as this would be really close to where my fingers are usually placed.
3. Can this be configured through emacs via emacs-lisp? Or, must this be configured through OS X settings such as how I changed the caps-lock key?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ummm... Isn't Meta alt? Or have you not yet fixed the default terminal key bindings so that alt actually works...?

Comment: I have made a few customizations here and there by searching the web and finding what I like, but I do not remember "default terminal key bindings" so how would I do that?

Comment: Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings -> click your profile -> Keyboard -> "Use option as Meta key". That way you have a normal terminal. Also, I would suggest iTerm2 over terminal.app, but that is a digression.

Comment: Is it possible to change the meta-key to ANY combination of keys? Right now I have `M-x` bound to `\C-x\C-m`.

Comment: Also, there is no, "Use option as Meta key" under the keyboard tab on my machine OS X 10.8.4

Comment: It's there, at the bottom. (terminal.app) [picture](http://demure.sdf.org/posts/Term-app_key-setting.png)